# Recommended way to retrieve large number of records using record IDs returned by getUpdated() call?

Tags: soap-api, bulk-api, replication

I'll start off by describing how I understand the intended use of the `getUpdated` method.

The Salesforce docs recommend using the `getUpdated()` method from their data replication API to retrieve records that have been updated in the a time window. The result of this query is an array of up to 600,000 record IDs and the `latestDateCovered` date, where `latestDateCovered` tells us up to which date the records are committed (not undergoing a transaction that could change them). We are supposed to use the `latestDateCovered` value as the start date of the next query, rather than the `end` value that was actually passed into the `getUpdated` call.

My question is, once I have the results, what is the best practice for retrieving the records with the IDs returned by `getUpdated`?

My first idea was to use the record IDs to create a query job with a clause `WHERE Id IN ('asd,'asd',...)` however since the query string has a 100,000 character limit, that limit is reached somewhere around 4000 or 5000 IDs. Since `getUpdated` can return up to 600,000 IDs this isn't going to work.

Another option then, is to create various query jobs, each with < 4000 IDs (to be sure the character limit isn't hit). This adds a lot of complexity though.

The option I settled on is to call `getUpdated` only for the purpose of obtaining the `latestDateCovered` values to use as the `start` value in the next query job. So the query clause looks like `WHERE SystemModstamp >= latestDateCovered AND SystemModstamp < end`. If `SystemModstamp` doesn't exist on the record I use `LastModifiedDate`.

Is this approach is reasonable? Is there a better approach?

Comment: getUpdated is a 2014 solution. Take a look at https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration for current options.

Comment: Thanks. The first thread has the solution I'd like to use, where I'd iterate through the returned IDs and pass them to `retrieve` in batches of 2000, however I'm accessing Salesforce via a nodejs app and the SOAP API retrieve function described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm?q=retrieve) doesn't seem to be available in jsforce or via the REST API. jsforce has a retrieve function that doesn't let me pass it the fields I want returned. Do you know of any other way to access the SOAP API function from the web?

Comment: The data ingestion doc doesn't seem to address the main concern I have with using the Change Data Capture events. We have customers who bulk update potentially 100s of thousands of records at a time, which means we get sent a change event for each one of those records and therefore we'd need to handle receiving that sudden spike in requests. A scheduled sync simplifies things a lot.

Comment: 100k events is on a higher side but still very much within the realm of event-driven architecture. For pulling back a sizeable number of records via REST, [bulk API](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#bulk-api) might be your best option.